# check valid email address with regex in JS failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

why not the alert trigger

```
if ( /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test('x@')){  
    alert('Please make sure the email is valid.');
}
```

Comment: do you know that html5 has a input type email ??

Comment: @madalinivascu yes I do.

Comment: This regular expression won't match a whole bunch of valid addresses (`foo+bar@gmail.com`, `user@domain.name`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Use below function.

```
    function IsValidEmail(emailText) {
    var atpos = emailText.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = emailText.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= emailText.length) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the logic inverted - you alert if something *is* a valid email address.

`if ( valid email address ) { alert }`, and `x@` is not a valid email address. No alert.

Try `!` to invert the result of the test:

```
if (! /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test('x@') ) {
    alert('Please make sure the email is valid.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this one. it will support after [dot] 2 ,3 character as
>   per your domain

```
var email_filter  = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (email_filter.test('yourEmail@gmail.com')) {
      alert('Email is valid');
    }
```